# asp net httpselfhostserver for controllers that do not extend ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Hi I am new to asp net programming and I am trying to test my asp net application using HttpSelfHostServer

link: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/self-hosting-in-Asp-Net-web-api/

by first setting up the server and then calling GET requests on my server on different controllers. (as described in the link)

This works perfectly when the controllers extend ApiController (which seems to be the base for asp net webapi applications) but it doesnt work for any other controller.

I am trying to get this to work with controllers that return views such as :

```
public class HomeController
    : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

IS this not possible to do with the HttpSelfHostServer? Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find the solution for this?

Comment: turns out it is not supported with my version of asp net mvc because what I wanted to do was only applicable with asp net web api. But with the new version of asp net mvc, (i believe asp net 6/ asp net vnext) this is supported. They basically combined asp net mvc and web api. Hope this helped